# Changing log level using properties from Spring Cloud config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-actuator, spring-logback

I want to change log levels using /refresh endpoint.
I know actuator exposes a different endpoint just for dealing with log levels, but I would like to do it from properties from config server.

If I put logging.level.com.foo.bar=ERROR in my local property files Spring is able to configure those values, but if I try to override value of logging.level.com.foo.bar from config server it is not picked and if I dont give local property and give it only through config server it fails and falls to debug.

I think it is somewhat related to @RefreshScope being not present on logback-spring.xml.

How to make logback-spring.xml eligible for /refresh

this is how my logback-spring.xml looks like at the moment.

```xml
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

 <springProperty scope="context" name="logLevel" source="logging.level"/>
    <logger name="com.foo.bar.springclient.spring.boot.management.logging" level="INFO" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="15 seconds">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

 <springProperty scope="context" name="logLevel" source="logging.level"/>
    <logger name="com.foo.bar.springclient.spring.boot.management.logging" level="INFO" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think refreshScope will help you in this case.

1. You can try below method to achieve your case.
2. Open actuator's `logger` endpoint in configuration.

> management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= "logger"

3. Please follow below code change

Inside any of the @refreshScope component add below piece of code

```
@EventListener(final RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event){
     // code to do POST call for changing desired logger level
}
```

The above method will be triggered after each refresh call so this may help you to achieve your goal.